# Windows update giving error 80070002 and manual update not working how to update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have been trying to update my pc from 20h1 to 20h2 but the windows update shows error message 80007002 and when I manually install the update using windows 10 update assistant it downloads completely and then even starts install and gets stuck at 87 percent on the screen where it says do not turn off. What to do?
This is the log file.

```
Matching Profile found: FindRollbackFailure - 3A43C9B5-05B3-4F7C-A955-88F991BB5A48
SetupDiag version: 1.6.0.0
System Information:
    Machine Name = 
    Manufacturer = 
    Model = 
    HostOSArchitecture = 1033
    FirmwareType = UEFI
    BiosReleaseDate = 20160513000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = A12
    BiosVersion = A12
    HostOSVersion = 10.0.19041
    HostOSBuildString = 19041.1.amd64fre.vb_release.191206-1406
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.19041.621 (vb_release_svc_prod1.201014-1758)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = CoreSingleLanguage
    RegisteredAV = Quick Heal Internet Security
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 12/20/2020 2:54:38 PM
    UpgradeEndTime = 12/20/2020 5:30:40 PM
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 02:36:02
    CV = Pi3IdU3SlEqpFx93
    ReportId = 


Error: SetupDiag reports rollback failure found.
Last Phase = Pre OOBE Boot
Last Operation = OOBE boot apply
Error = 0xC1900101-0x4000D
LogEntry: 

Refer to "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Debug/system-error-codes" for error information.

Last Setup Phase:
Phase Name: Pre OOBE Boot
    Phase Started: 12/20/2020 4:37:50 PM
    Phase Ended: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Phase Time Delta: 00:00:00
    Completed Successfully? False


Last Setup Operation:
Operation Name: OOBE boot apply
    Operation Started: 12/20/2020 4:37:50 PM
    Operation Ended: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    Operation Time Delta: 0:00:00:00.0000000
    Completed Successfully? False
```

Comment: You will have to provide the log file from Setup Diag to diagnose the reason you are unable to install the feature pack. Pleased edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Try the Windows Update troubleshooting steps referred to in this article  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/sbs/windows/fix-windows-update-errors-18b693b5-7818-5825-8a7e-2a4a37d6d787?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#letmefixit   .  The troubleshooting steps often lead to a resolution.

Comment: [The error code is due to an incompatible driver being installed.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolution-procedures)  You will have to now run WinDbg on the ump file that was created and is located in `$Windows.~BT\Sources\Rollback ` in order for us to diagnose the problem.  Performing a Windows Update reset **WILL NOT** resolve your problem.  The failure code will also not be resolved by DISM commands. The only solution is to identify the driver that is incompatible.

Comment: @Tushar_Jain follow @Ramhound's suggestion or please share the Windows Update log files to analyze the error code 0x8007002: Open the Windows Explorer, navigate to `C:\Windows\logs` and then copy and paste the **CBS** Folder on your desktop, zip it and then upload it on [wetransfer](https://wetransfer.com) and share the link here please.

Comment: Well sorry i had another problem so i ended up resetting my pc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Update is problematic and can fail in many ways.

Below is a list of advice that may help Windows Update work better:

- Run the Windows Update troubleshooter in:
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters >
  Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter*
- Run Microsoft's [Windows Update Troubleshooter for Windows 10](//support.microsoft.com/help/4027322)
- Reset Windows Update components by running these commands in an elevated
  Command Prompt:

  ```
  net stop wuauserv
  net stop cryptSvc
  net stop bits
  net stop msiserver
  Ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
  Ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
  net start msiserver
  net start wuauserv
  net start cryptSvc
  net start bits
  ```

  If all goes well, delete the `.old` folders (or return them if a problem
  arrives).
- Run the DISM tool in an elevated Command Prompt:

  ```
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
  ```
- Run the following in an elevated PowerShell shell:

  ```
  SC config trustedinstaller start=auto
  ```
- If nothing fixes the problem, use a heavy gun:
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](//tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the stopped windows update services worked for me. THere are other fixes mentioned [here](https://droidtheory.com/fix-windows-update-error-0x80070002/) which can help you in fixing the error 80070002 on your pc.