# Update KB4577015 failed with 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING

Tags: updates

I have updated a Windows 2012R2 to Windows 2016 in Oktober. Since this time the CU Windows Updates do not work. I allways get the Error 0x80073701.
I tried
-SFC /SCANNOW => no error found
-DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth => no error found
For checking, if the Updates packages are OK I tried to use WSUSOFFLINE. Same result.

I think there is some reciurce missing. But I don't find the point.
The CBS.Log from the last try is here: http://www.filedropper.com/cbspersist20210126213217

I am not sure how to go on. maybe anybody has a suggestion?

Thanks for your comments.
Olaf

I run DISM.EXE /online /get-packages with this result ( unfortunalty in german)

Paketidentit„t : Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Feature Pack
Installationszeit : 16.07.2016 13:25

Paketidentit„t : Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-Server-Common-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Feature Pack
Installationszeit : 16.07.2016 13:25

Paketidentit„t : Microsoft-Windows-ServerCore-SKU-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.14393.0
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Feature Pack
Installationszeit : 16.07.2016 13:25

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_DotNetRollup~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4261.2
Status : Abgel”st
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit :

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_DotNetRollup~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.4311.2
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit : 13.01.2021 19:25

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB3176936~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.2
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit : 17.10.2016 09:01

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB3192137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.0
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit : 12.09.2016 11:30

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB4486129~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.2919
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit : 01.10.2020 04:53

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB4486135~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.2752
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit : 01.02.2021 17:25

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB4535680~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.2
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Security Update
Installationszeit : 13.01.2021 19:22

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB4565912~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.3801.1.1
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Security Update
Installationszeit : 01.10.2020 00:17

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB4576750~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.3926.1.3
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Security Update
Installationszeit : 01.10.2020 00:19

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB4577586~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.4
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit : 26.01.2021 20:34

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_KB4580325~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.1
Status : Installiert
Versionstyp : Security Update
Installationszeit : 15.10.2020 17:32

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.206.1.2
Status : Abgel”st
Versionstyp : Update
Installationszeit : 17.10.2016 09:09

Paketidentit„t : Package_for_RollupFix~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~14393.3930.1.5
Status : Teilweise installiert
Versionstyp : Security Update
Installationszeit : 01.10.2020 06:25

Comment: Your file is inaccessible

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of **DISM.EXE /online /get-packages** to the body of your question.  Be sure to format it.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1611408/8672) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have at least found the solution for the update Failure in the CBS.log
The solution was to install the missing KB from Microsoft manually.
windows10.0-kb4577015-x64_0e838646b432d7b5360fffd0f12365ca181d475d.msu
After this went well, the installation of the Update went automatically.
"2021-01 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4598243)"

Thanks